I can't run almost command in CLI termin after I install python3.11 in ubuntu20.04
I try to use gnome-terminal,sudo update-alternatives --config python3or command apt,apt-get,ls
All callback like
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

I install python like this https://blog.csdn.net/DEVELOPERAA/article/details/133743389
